# Electric field outside conductive surface with internal charge density

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, conductors, boundary-conditions

My professor told me that if you have a charge distribution $\rho \ne 0$ defined on a bounded region $V \subset  \mathbb{R}^3$ whose boundary is a regular $2$-dimensional surface $\partial V= S$ which is a conductor, then the potential that satisfies $\Delta \phi = - \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$ subject to the boundary conditions $\phi|_S = 0$ will also satisfy

$$\nabla \phi \cdot \mathbf{n} = \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}, \tag1$$

where $\mathbf{n}$ is the outward unit normal vector field to the surface $S$.

If I use the boundary conditions of electrostatics

$$\nabla \phi_{\text{inside}}\cdot \mathbf{n}- \nabla \phi_{\text{above}}\cdot \mathbf{n} =\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}, $$

I must conclude that $\nabla \phi_{\text{above}}\cdot \mathbf{n}$ =0. But why?

Because of $\rho$, the electric field inside $V$ does not vanish in general, and we would have induced charge on the "inner surface" of conductor with opposite signal of $\rho$. But what about the "outer surface".

As far as I know, there would be some induced charge with same sign as $\rho$ and so we could not conclude that the field right above $S$ would be zero.

Am I missing some crucial point in my analysis?